# F1 visa for vacation purpose?

Tags: visas, usa, f1-visas, mexican-citizens

I m a student in the US with a current F1 visa, i traveled back to Mexico for summer vacation. I m Mexican, my current B1/B2 is expired and is under renewal. In the meanwhile i  want to travel during my  vacations  for a short trip to Miami for  visiting some friends, can i travel to Miami without the B1/B2 visa? And use the F1 instead?   Then im traveling back to Mexico, finsh my vacationd and on August travel back to my university in Boston.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems a little questionable to me.  On the other hand, if you wait for your B visa and show both the B visa and the F visa when you arrive in Miami, explaining that the purpose of your present trip is entirely a "pleasure" visit, it's entirely possible that you'd nonetheless be admitted in F-1 status.  I think there was a similar case reported here a year or two ago.

Answer (score 1):

It’s perfectly fine. F1 students are allowed to (and many do) go home on vacation. Why are you even bothering to apply for a B visa? It’s unnecessary and You don’t need it until you complete your study program.

**As long as you’re in valid F1 student status**, you can travel in and out of the USA for as long as you like and as frequently as you like. During the summer break it’s assumed you will enroll for the following semester so far as your program has not ended, and hence your F1 visa is still valid and able to be used to travel in and out of the USA.

During vacations you’re allowed to live in the USA or anywhere you choose. This is not a problem at all.